# preg_match is not validation roman character for Unicode regular expression

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have following requirement:

- Match all Unicode Character.(Not specific Roman Characters)
- Maximum Characters will 255.
- Don't accept Numeric characters.

I have written the following code and regular expression for that. It is working perfectly for ASCII characters and satisfying all requirements mentioned above but it is failing when I am using Roman Characters.

Please let me know where I am wrong.

```
<?php
    $text = "ăâáéíîó";
    $pattern = "/^[p{L}p{M}*+]{1,255}$/"; 

    $ret = preg_match($pattern,$text,$match);

    echo "Return Value =  $ret";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($match);
?>
```

Output :

```
Return Value = 0
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following fixes:

- The category classes are to be defined with `\` - `\p{L}`, `\p{M}`.
- The letter with possible diacritic patterns should be *grouped* inside a grouping construct not a char class
- The `/u` modifier is required when dealing with Unicode.

Use

```
$pattern = "/^(?:\p{L}\p{M}*+){1,255}$/u";
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/F7o9Rj)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have defined category classes with "\" but during formatting it was removed mistakenly by me. I tried the above expression as well but forget to add "/u" .